# Send a SQL-statement as a parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm wondering if there is any clever solution for sending a whole SQL-statement as a parameter to a stored procedure that's already holding date-parameters.

See below.

```
CREATE procedure sp_GetDataByDate
 @startdate datetime,
 @enddate datetime,
 @sqlStatement varchar(max)
as  
begin
   -- Here I want my SELECT-anything-somehow-statement
   @sqlStatement
   WHERE dbo.DummyDataTable.CreatedDT BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
end
```

A solution where you first take the SQL-statement and create a temporary table with that data to later on use the date-parameters to filter out what you want might work but it might be heavy since it's alot of data in this database.

Thanks

Comment: You'd better not do like so. This will be a huge hole in your security and wide open door for an SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. I'm open for other solutions to solve this.

Comment: What goal do you try to achieve? Is it a select from different tables or a select different columns from different tables or something? It sounds as to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: For a bit of reading on what @Denis is saying re: security risks. https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-risks-of-using-execute-sql-script

Comment: The user should be able to choose different SELECT-statements from a frontend-environment where they also pick dates from a datepicker.

Comment: Definitely an XY Problem. What is the *real" problem you're tryouts nf to solve here?

Comment: The safe way to do this is to send simple values from the frontend and expand them to SQL statements on the backend. Just as an example, if the value of the dropdown is "1" then you pass `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name="Bobby Tables";`, if it's "2" you pass `DROP TABLE students;` and so on. Never let even partial SQL queries come from the frontend.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use DQE(dynamic query execution) in sql server with this ability you can create TSQL with string abilities and execute that.

but this solution have some security and performance problems.

in this case hackers can attack your site with SQL Injection attack and maybe that have some performance problem like plan catch and parameter sniffing at sql server.

best solution is create different SP for loading Information.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetDataByDate
     @startdate datetime,
     @enddate datetime,
     @sqlStatement varchar(max)
    AS  
    BEGIN
       -- Here I want my SELECT-anything-somehow-statement
     SET @sqlStatement +=' WHERE dbo.DummyDataTable.CreatedDT BETWEEN '+CHAR(39)+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR , @startdate , 120 )+CHAR(39)+  ' AND ' +CHAR(39)+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR , @enddate , 120 )+CHAR(39)

     PRINT @sqlStatement 

     EXEC(@sqlStatement )
    END
```

[DQE Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Think over what will be when you sometime get from your frontend `sqlStatement = 'DROP TABLE dbo.DummyDataTable; --'`

Comment: Like I said on the other (now deleted) answer, this is a huge security problem and should **not** be used.

Comment: @nipple1450 - Denis Rubashkin is absolutely right - not even parameters can save you from such a bad way of scripting SQL. You also have the overhead (depending on the complexity of the injected SQL) of compilation of the passed code.

Comment: Mahdi Rahimi - you should not promote this as an answer to the question. Suggest an alternative.

Comment: Well. The SQL-statements are added by myself. They can only choose templates in a dropdown which is SELECT-statements.

Comment: and how you are you ensuring that those statements are "clean" @nipple1450? Sounds like, instead, you should have different **parametrised** SP's the user can execute.

Comment: @Paul Yes i agree with you but i just answer his question i will change my answer and tell him about alternative way. thank you

Comment: @Paul we dont know exactly the business we see only the problem

Comment: @nipple1450 Just because no-one has said this straight yet – it's trivially easy for the user to change the values in frontend, or even bypass your frontend completely and send whatever they want to the backend. You can't trust what's coming from the frontend.